# graphql mongoose must be Output Type but got: undefined

Tags: mongodb, graphql

schema:

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const User = require("../models/user");

const { 
    GraphQLObjectType, 
    GraphQLString, 
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLList
} = graphql;

const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:'Company',
    fields: () => ({
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        catchPhrase: { type: GraphQLString },
        bs: { type: GraphQLString },
    })
})

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id : { type: GraphQLID },
        name : { type: GraphQLString },
        username : { type: GraphQLString },
        email : { type: GraphQLString },
        address : { type: GraphQLString },
        phone : { type: GraphQLInt },
        website : { type: GraphQLString },
        company : new GraphQLList(CompanyType)
    })
})

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: { type: GraphQLID }
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                return User.findById(args.id);
            }
        },
        users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
            resolve(parent, args){
                return User.find({});
            }
        }
    }
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
});
```

model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Scheme = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Scheme({
    id : Number,
    name : String,
    username : String,
    email : String,
    address : Object,
    phone : Number,
    website : String,
    company : Object

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Here i am trying to fetch data from mongodb database.
I have setup my server with expressjs with graphql and using mongoose for mongodb client.

But while making quesry in graphiql i am getting below error:

```
{
    "errors": [
    {
        "message": "The type of User.company must be Output Type but got: undefined."
    }
    ]
}
```

My result is with nested json so i am using GraphQLList .

Please have a look where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
company : {type: CompanyType}
```

and schema should be

```
const userSchema = new Scheme({
id : Number,
name : String,
username : String,
email : String,
address : Object,
phone : Number,
website : String,
company : {
    name: String,
    catchPhrase: String,
    bs: String
}
})
```